# Como faço para converter FileList para Array em Javascript?

Tags: javascript

No Javascript, ao selecionar retornar os valores selecionados do arquivo de um `input[type=file]`, ele retorna os valores dentro de um `FileList`.

Exemplo:

```js
document.querySelector('#files').addEventListener('change', function () {
   console.log(this.files.constructor); // Isso não é um Array, é um FileList
   console.log(this.files)
})
```

```html
<div>Selecione um ou mais arquivos:</div>
<input type="file" multiple id="files" />
```

O problema é que o `FileList` não tem operações comuns de um `Array` normal, como o `forEach`, `map` e afins.

Veja:

```js
document.querySelector('#files').addEventListener('change', function () {
   console.log('Filelist:', this.files.forEach); // retorna 'undefined'
   console.log('Array:', [].forEach); // retorna a função
})
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple id="files" />
```

Eu gostaria de saber se é possível converter `FileList` em um `Array` comum em Javascript.

Comment: Tentou simplesmente aplicar os métodos de array no FileList? Por exemplo, `const fileNames = Array.prototype.map.call(fileListInstance, (file) => file.name);`.

Comment: Eu estava esperando você responder isso @bfavaretto ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Você pode usar `Array.from()`

> Referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

```js
document.querySelector('#files').addEventListener('change', function () {
   console.log(Array.from(this.files))
})
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple id="files" />
```

Answer (score 3):

A respostas anterior utilizava `Array.from` para converter `FileList` em `Array`, porém pelo que percebi o suporte para essa função ainda não está disponível em todos os navegadores:

[image: Suporte ao Array.from]

É possível obter o mesmo resultado através da função `Array.prototype.slice`. 
Basta chamar `[].slice.call(this.files)` para obter o valor em `Array`.

Veja:

```js
document.querySelector('#files').addEventListener('change', function () {
   var files = [].slice.call(this.files);
   console.log(files.constructor); // Isso é um array
   console.log(files.length); 
})
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" multiple />
```

A função [`Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) tem compatibilidade com navegadores mais antigos

Answer (score 2):

#### Object.values(), 'Spread sintax' ..., call(), apply(), Array.from(), 
 'Argumentos Spread' ... + 'Rest Parameters' ...

`Object.values()`, `'Spread sintax' ...`, `call()`, `apply()`, `Array.from()`, convertem um `objeto FileList` num  `objecto Array de objetos File` e consequentemente acessível a todos os `métodos Array` incluindo `.map()` e `.forEach()`.

```js
document.querySelector('#files').addEventListener('change', function () {

console.log( Object.values( this.files ) )
console.log( [ ... this.files ] )
console.log( [].slice.call( this.files ) )
console.log( [].slice.apply( this.files ) )
console.log( Array.from( this.files ) )
console.log( ( (..._)=>_)(...this.files) ) /*argumentos spread + rest parameters*/

console.log( Object.values( this.files ) instanceof Array )
console.log( [ ... this.files ] instanceof Array )
console.log( [].slice.call( this.files ) instanceof Array )
console.log( [].slice.apply( this.files ) instanceof Array )
console.log( Array.from( this.files ) instanceof Array )
console.log( ( (..._)=>_)(...this.files) instanceof Array )

} )
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple id="files" />
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]